# Print files in S3 matching some specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket, in the bucket i have one folder and inside the folder i have many sub folders like mentioned below.

**Bucket path: s3://path1/path2**

Inside path2 folders will be like

```
D1D04021200040609001
D1D04021200040612001
D3D04020000040603001
D3D04020000040606001
D6D05091200051512001
D6D05091200051518001
G1S05101200051217001
G1S05101200051218001
G4S05091200051012001
G4S05091200051013001
```

I have many folders like this. I just want to check specific file exists or not using a pattern.
How can i do this in linux

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket path1/path2 --query "Contents[?contains(Key, `D1D0`)]"
```

am getting error like....**invalid bucket name bucket name should be in regex**

I ran the below query

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket name --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D0518')]" --query "sum(Contents[].Size)" --output text
```

But i wonder y i am  getting 10 lines of output...
i need the total size of the files staring with **A1D0518**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxsMz.png)

Kindly help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by "check specific file exists or not using a pattern"? Please edit our question to explain this in more details.

Comment: @sharad I have added what i have tried...could u pls help me out on this

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need to search the file with a pattern....eg with the first 3 letters of a file

Comment: From the documentation I gather that the bucket name in your case is only `path1`. Then there would be no bucket named `path1/path2`, which is what the error message says. Bucket names are listed with the aptly named `list-buckets` subcommand.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Path 1 is the bucket name....But inside path1 there is folder(path2) ...and inside the path2 only all the files are present....
Can u pls help me on this

Comment: Well, most simply: Did you try `aws s3api list-objects --bucket path1`?? Does it work? When you see your folders there (among all other objects) the next task is to filter them out, either  with a shell command like grep or with s3api means, somehow (note that I have zero experience with cloud computing). Maybe this page helps: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  when i used 'aws s3api list-objects --bucket path1` its not only listing folders...Its is alsi listing all the subfolders....So i think we need to give path1/path2 to go into specific folder

Comment: Ah, good, it worked. Now you learned that the `--bucket` option takes a bucket name, not more, not less. Do you find that counter-intuitive? Now on to step two, filtering for the desired folder names. Did you read the page I linked? Do you think the way the author uses the `--prefix` command to filter  a bunch of access log files might fit your needs?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica i ran like aws s3api list-objects --bucket path1 --prefix path2 it worked!!!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica awesome it worked
aws s3api list-objects --bucket path1--prefix path2 --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'E4Y0')]"

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yup...now my need is i need get the total size of all files that start with `E4Y0` HOw can i do that

Comment: If I had time I would learn the S3 API with you ;-). But I don't. So read the documentation, obtain the sizes of each file, sum it up with the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to calculate the total size of all objects that **contain a given string**.

This can be done with:

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "sum(Contents[?contains(Key, 'E4Y0')].Size)"
```

If, instead, you are looking for the total size of all objects that **start with a given string**, use:

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix E4Y0 --query "sum(Contents[].Size)"
```

Please note that `Prefix` looks at the full path, so it might include subdirectories. So, first have it print the names with `--query Contents[].Key` to make sure you are including the correct objects.

**Update based on your comment:**

To find objects in a given directory that being with `E4Y0` use:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix path1/path2/path3/E4Y0 --query "sum(Contents[].Size)"
```

But test it first by using this to list the objects being selected:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix path1/path2/path3/E4Y0 --query "Contents[].Key"
```

Comment: But in my case i need to go inside the specific folder and then i need to get the size of the files starting with "E4Y0"

Comment: As of now...i used the query
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --prefix path1/path2/path3 --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'E4Y0')]" --output text

Comment: From the above query...how can i modify to get the size of the files starting with E4Y0

Comment: Can u pls help me

Comment: Updated answer. Please spend some time looking at our examples and you should be able to modify them to fit your own particular situation.

Comment: I have tried the query and i have updated my question section..but am not sure y am getting 10 lines of output....instead of one output...I need total size of the files matching the pattern

Comment: You should only have ONE `--query` in your command. See my first example above.